# not scraping website with PHP

Tags: php

This code is currently returning an empty array.
The desired output is the content of the 3 day Weather forecast summary.

For example:
"Heavy rain (total 23mm), heaviest during Sat night. Very mild (max 18°C on Mon morning, min 12°C on Sat night). Wind will be generally light. "

```
   $contents=file_get_contents("http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/San-Francisco/forecasts/latest");

   preg_match('/3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:<\/b>\s*<span class="phrase">(.*?)</s', $contents,$matches);
   print_r($matches);
```

Comment: It means it couldn't find the needle in the haystack...

Comment: there are many weather API"s please use one of them rather than scraping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this isn't working is because the actual website got a lot more between "Summary:" and the "<span class..."

What you could try (that seems to work) is to change it into the simpler form:

```
$contents=file_get_contents("http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/San-Francisco/forecasts/latest");

preg_match('/<span class="phrase">(.*?)<\/s/', $contents,$matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

This will pick out more matches, but since we're only interested in the first we can just pick that one out from the array.